# WebSphere MQ Q Program Usage

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a queue manager QM_TEST created using the following MQSC command:

```
  SET AUTHREC OBJTYPE(QMGR) GROUP('mq-user') AUTHADD(INQ,DSP,CONNECT,SET,SETALL)
  SET AUTHREC PROFILE(SYSTEM.MQEXPLORER.REPLY.MODEL) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) GROUP('mq-user') AUTHADD(INQ,DSP,GET)
  SET AUTHREC PROFILE(SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) GROUP('mq-user') AUTHADD(INQ,DSP,PUT)
  DEFINE CHANNEL ($cname) CHLTYPE (SVRCONN) TRPTYPE (TCP) MCAUSER('tcs-mq-user') REPLACE
  SET CHLAUTH($cname) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS(*) MCAUSER('tcs-mq-user')
  DEFINE QLOCAL ($dlqname) REPLACE
  SET AUTHREC PROFILE($dlqname) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) GROUP('mq-user') AUTHADD(ALL)
  ALTER  QMGR DEADQ($dlqname) FORCE
  DEFINE LISTENER ($lname) TRPTYPE (TCP) CONTROL (QMGR) PORT ($port)
  START LISTENER ($lname)
```

I have two queues TEST1 and TEST2 created using:

```
DEFINE QLOCAL ($qname) GET(ENABLED) PUT(ENABLED) MAXDEPTH($maxdepth) REPLACE
SET AUTHREC PROFILE($qname) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) GROUP('mq-user') AUTHADD(ALL)
```

I am trying to copy messages from TEST1 to TEST2 using the q program utility:

> q -xb -mQM_TEST -iTEST1 -mQM_TEST -oTEST2 -p20

However I get this error:

> MQSeries Q Program by Paul Clarke [ V6.0.0 Build:May  2 2012 ]
>   Connecting ...failed. MQCONNX on object 'QM_TEST' returned 2035 Not
>   authorized..

I am running WebSphere MQ v7.1. *q* SupportPac is installed on the server and I am executing the q command on the server. I can't figure out a way to pass the channel name TEST_CHANNEL and port number 1414, is that the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is connecting to the QMgr in bindings mode via shared memory rather than using the SVRCONN channel.  You can verify this by `ALTER QMGR AUTHOREV(ENABLED)` then looking at the authorization event that is produced in the QMgr event queue.  If you have installed [SupportPac MS0P](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0P) you can right-click on the queue and select "Format event messages" to see it in human-readable format.  Either way, you should see that the ID being used to connect is not `tcs-mq-user` but rather whatever ID you are using to run the Q program.  Try:

```
q -lmqic -xc -iTEST1 -oTEST2 -p20
```

The program will prompt you for the channel details when run with `-xc`.

The Q program can dump queues to files but it is not designed for that.  The QLoad program from [SupportPac MO03](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMO03) *is* designed for that and will capture all aspects of the message and, if you are suitably authorized, also restore them intact.  This includes message ID, timestamp, etc.

Finally, a quick note about the `AUTHREC` statements in your post.  Since you have bothered to create a low-privleged `MCAUSER` and set authorities for it, I presume that you would like that ID not to have administrative privileges.  Please be aware that granting a user `+set` or `+setall` on the QMgr allows them to manage authorization records using WMQ Explorer or anything else that uses PCF commands.  Consider restricting authorities on the QMgr to `+dsp +inq +connect`.

Generally, the applications don't get access to the DLQ but rather get access to an application-specific backout queue.  If the app is granted access to the DLQ it is usually only to put messages there and not to get them back out.  This is because the DLQ is a system-wide resource and if the QMgr is shared, the messages from multiple apps might land in the DLQ.  As a security precaution, restrict delete access on that queue to administrators.  This way someone cleaning up after their app can't accidentally (or otherwise) delete the messages belonging to another app.

**UPDATE:**
Reviewing your post, I noticed another discrepancy.  I had assumed that you were getting the 2035 Authorization Error because you were connecting in bindings mode with an ID other than `mqm` or `tcs-mq-user`.  After looking again, I realized that you never authorized the `mq-user` group to the queues you are trying to access.  You authorized it to the Command Queue and the reply model which aren't used in this scenario.  (WMQ Explorer uses them.)  So, add the following rules:

```
SET AUTHREC PROFILE(TEST1) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) GROUP('mq-user') AUTHADD(PUT,GET,INQ,BROWSE)
SET AUTHREC PROFILE(TEST2) OBJTYPE(QUEUE) GROUP('mq-user') AUTHADD(PUT,GET,INQ,BROWSE)
```

This will solve the auths problem if in fact you are connecting as `tcs-mq-user`.

There isn't a way to pass the channel to Q on the command line, as far as I know, but it does accept the standard [MQSERVER variable](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/cs12350_.htm).  For example:

```
export MQSERVER="$cname/TCP/localhost($port)"
```

...where `$cname` is the channel name and `$port` is the port.  Here's my test:

```
tcs-mq-user:~> export MQSERVER="TEST.SVRCONN/TCP/localhost(1414)"
tcs-mq-user:~> q -xb -iTEST1 -mQMTEST -lmqic
MQSeries Q Program by Paul Clarke [ V6.0.0 Build:May  2 2012 ]
Connecting ...connected to 'JMSDEMO'.
No more messages.
tcs-mq-user:~>
```

As to why its not finding the client libs, do you have them installed?

```
tcs-mq-user:~> rpm -qa | grep MQSeriesClient
MQSeriesClient-7.5.0-0
```

Comment: Wow, You answered three questions! All of them help me to improve MQ. Let me ask follow up question on the orginal issue.

Comment: Ha ha! Feel free to go vote up three of my other answers.  :-)  I'll keep an eye out for new questions.

Comment: I get "Error loading MQ library mqic32 RC(11)" when I try to run this on Server, which is where I'd like to test it. When I remove -lmqic32 I get "MQCONNX on object 'QM_MCT' returned 2035 Not authorized..". Another question I have is how can I pass the channel name in the command?

Comment: Updated the response with the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working in the "client" machine using MQSERVER variable. Btw, I do thave the auths set for the queue but it is ALL. Of course I need to restrict this further on these queues along with DLQ.

Comment: I still get get "MQCONNX on object 'QM_MCT' returned 2035 Not authorized.." when I execute "q -xb -iTEST1 -mQM_TEST" on the MQ Server. The queue object script largely remains the same as in the original post. I even tried setting up the MQSERVEr variable.

Comment: Did you `alter qmgr authorev(enabled)` yet? If so, it would be REALLY helpful to view the error in SYSTEM.ADMIN.QMGR.EVENT and see which user ID it is choking on. Since you authorized the queues to tcs-mq-user, I'm back to thinking you are connecting in bindings mode using an ID that is not authorized. Is the WMQ client even installed on the QMgr host server?

Comment: No WMQ Client is NOT installed on the MQ Server? Is that recommended? Do we always have to use -lmqic32?

Comment: If you are trying to communicate with WMQ using channels instead of shared memory, you MUST install the client libs.  On the other hand, you can run the Q program in bindings mode by omitting the `-lmqic` parm. In that case the ID being used to run the program must have access to connect to the QMgr.  If you `alter qmgr authorev(enabled)` you can see what ID failed an API call, the options sit requested, the object it failed on, etc.

Comment: I think I have an idea now what is going on, did not yet get time to work on it. Thank for the tangent answers in your original question. What AUTHADDS are typically given to DLQs? I want to restrict that. I have taken out set, setall now from QMGR.

Comment: As for the original question of execution of q program on the server, tcs-mq-user is a non login password. I was not doing that. Per your example I need to su into tcs-mq-user to do this, which I can't.